# Can't conect two frames with custom signals

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to connect two frames with a custom signal but I'm not really getting it.

This code is just an example of what im trying to do in my program, my objective is to transfer data between frames.

Files:

(sender)

```
    #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
    #define MAINWINDOW_H

    #include <QMainWindow>

    namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
    }

    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    signals:
        void send();

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
        ~MainWindow();

    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    private slots:
        void on_pushButton_clicked();
    };

    #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

On "mainwindow.cpp" I've got the void on_pushButton_clicked() that emits the signal and shows the new frame:

private slot void:

```
        void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
    {
        emit send();
        Dialog sw;
        sw.setModal(true);
        sw.exec();
    }
```

(receiver):

```
        #ifndef DIALOG_H
    #define DIALOG_H

    #include <QDialog>
    #include <QDebug>

    namespace Ui {
    class Dialog;
    }

    class Dialog : public QDialog
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
        ~Dialog();

    private slots:
        void receive();

    private:
        Ui::Dialog *ui;
        int a;
    };

    #endif // DIALOG_H
```

and the .cpp:

```
        #include "dialog.h"
    #include "ui_dialog.h"
    #include "mainwindow.h"


    Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
        QDialog(parent),
        ui(new Ui::Dialog)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        a=0;
        MainWindow w;
        connect(&w, SIGNAL(send()), this, SLOT(receive()));
        qDebug() << a;
    }


    Dialog::~Dialog()
    {
        delete ui;
    }

    void Dialog::receive(){
        qDebug() << "ola";
        a++;
    }
```

Conclusion:
So basicly the function Dialog doesn't print the qDebug(), and 'a' is still 0, so I conclude that the connection isn't set/executed.

Thanks all, 
Best regards, 
Dylan Lopes.

edit: Wrote a conclusion on the end of the post.

Comment: We are not getting it either. What's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mencion it, i edited a conclusion on the end of the post.

Comment: 'On "mainwindow.cpp" i've got the void on_pushButton_clicked() that emits the signal and shows the new frame,'

Comment: Your object **"MainWindow w"** was created in the constructor of the Dialog so when it go out of the scope of the view it will be deleted, so try to move it to private section of the class and I think all'll be ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the code in your `Dialog` constructor...

```
MainWindow w;
connect(&w, SIGNAL(send()), this, SLOT(receive()));
```

This creates a locally scoped `MainWindow` on the stack and connects its `send()` signal to the `Dialog`'s `receive()` slot.  But the `MainWindow` -- and, hence, the connection -- will be destroyed as soon as the `Dialog` constructor has completed.

In addition, looking at `MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked`...

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    emit send();
    Dialog sw;
    sw.setModal(true);
    sw.exec();
}
```

You emit the `send()` signal *before* constructing the `Dialog`.

I don't really know enough about what you're trying to achieve to provide a definitive answer, but in the interests of getting some kind of signal/slot interaction you might want to do the following: change the `Dialog` constructor to...

```
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Dialog)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        a=0;
        qDebug() << a;
    }
```

And change `MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked` to...

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Dialog sw;
    connect(this, &MainWindow::send, &sw, &Dialog::receive);
    emit send();
    sw.setModal(true);
    sw.exec();
}
```

That should at least result in `Dialog::receive` being invoked and you can work from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it invoked Dialog::receive. How can i force the Dialog constructor to wait for the connection before he does the qDebug()?

Answer (score 0):

Connection between a signal and a slot doesn't mean that the signal function will be triggered.

You still need to emit your signal so that `a` gets updated.

Creating an empty slot isn't working either, as slots are the receiving point of a signal. In this case, `on_pushButton_clicked()` gets triggered whent he push button is clicked. This doesn't trigger `send` unless you call `EMIT(send())` (IIRC, you emit a signal with EMIT, is that still the case?).

Comment: I edited the post with a function in the "mainwindow.cpp" that emits the signal

Comment: Well, does it work now, or not? Your question keeps on evolving.

Comment: No, i had already the emit(send()) just forgot to put the code on the post